# unrecognized content encoding type

Tags: r, curl

I was getting errors with the [taxize](https://github.com/ropensci/taxize) R package, and have narrowed it down to an error being returned by `curl::curl_fetch_memory`. I find that the following returns an error on my linux computer, but works fine on my Mac.

```
x <- curl::curl_fetch_memory('https://www.google.com')
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://www.google.com") : 
  Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands identity content encodings.
```

I checked my version of libcurl (installed via linuxbrew):

```
$ curl-config --version
libcurl 7.63.0`
```

and here is my R session info:

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation 7.6 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openblas/0.3.5/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.5.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] curl_3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2
```

Any thoughts regarding what the problem might be? Thanks!

Comment: `taxize` pkg maintainer here. Are you still having the problem?

Comment: No, this now appears to be resolved!

Comment: Great, glad it works